# How to validate 1 XML file against 2 XSD's?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need a user-supplied XML file to match 1 of 2 possible schemas.

Following along this tutorial, as our "real" XSD's aren't finished yet:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx

Except I want the "inverse" of that tutorial. So I modified it so that there's a second `xsdMarkup`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xsdMarkup1 = CreateXsd(2);
    string xsdMarkup2 = CreateXsd(3);

    XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup1)));
    schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup2)));

    XDocument doc1 = CreateXDoc(2);
    XDocument doc2 = CreateXDoc(3);

    Validate(doc1, schemas);
    Validate(doc2, schemas);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Expected Output**: Both should validate as the first schema supports `Child1` `Child2`, and the second schema supports `Child1`, `Child3`.

The methods `CreateXsd`, `CreateXDoc`, and `Validate` just contain the code that was there from the tutorial. The `int` I pass to it just gets appended to the second `Child` element so you have `Child1` and either `Child2` or `Child3` as the second element, depending on what's passed.

When I run this, `Validate(doc1, schemas);` crashes with this error:

> The global element 'Root' has already been declared.

It seems like because my two `xsdMarkup` variables use the same `xmlns` value, it's simply appending the schema to the first schema. OK, no problem, I'll just change the namespace for the second one... Nope; that crashes because the URL isn't valid and I don't know what I could substitute instead.

So, hypothetically, say I had two functioning schemas. Can I call `XmlSchemaSet.Add` twice then call `XDocument.Validate(myXmlSchemaSetObj, someValidationEventHandlerDefintion);` to validate 1 file against multiple schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it fails for you because you specify "" as the [targetNamespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hh8b082(v=vs.110).aspx) both times. It sounds like you are still developing this project, so we can get you "patched up for the show" by breaking-out the logic a bit for now.

P.S. You can also try passing a null value instead of "" as the targetNameSpace in your code above...maybe that would work, too!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xsdMarkup1 = CreateXsd(2);
    string xsdMarkup2 = CreateXsd(3);

    XmlSchemaSet schemas1 = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemas1.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup1)));
    XmlSchemaSet schemas2 = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemas2.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup2)));

    XDocument doc1 = CreateXDoc(2);
    XDocument doc2 = CreateXDoc(3);

    Validate(doc1, schemas1);
    Validate(doc1, schemas2);
    Validate(doc2, schemas1);
    Validate(doc2, schemas2);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: That might work, I'll try it in a moment. But what is the difference between an `XmlSchema` and an `XmlSchemaSet`? I would think the latter would be a container, of sorts, for a collection of `XmlSchema` objects no? I figured you could basically store a number of schemas to validate against individually. Seems rather counter intuitive to have to create a separate Set object for each schema I want to validate against...

Comment: I think it breaks for you because you specify "" as  the targetNamespace twice. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hh8b082(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This does work. While I don't understand why I have to do it that way, if it works, that's all that matters. The empty quotes (or null) forces it to use the namespace defined in the XSD itself. In this case, yea, it's using the same w3.org URL.

Comment: yes, that was what I was shooting for, see my comment above about targetNamespace

Comment: P.S. You can also try passing a null values instead of "" as the targetNameSpace's in your code above...maybe that would work, too!

Comment: I tried removing the `xmlns:xsd=...` attribute from the `xsd:schema` node and instead passed unique strings each time I called `Add(string, string)` on a single `XmlSchemaSet` object and that was causing issues as well. Screw it! I'll just use your method. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: if you need it to work later, try null instead of "" but dont try "null"...this tells C# to get it from the XSD

Comment: I wonder if this is an error in the documentation. If you look at `XmlSchemaSet.Add(string, XmlReader)` it states "`null` or `String.Empty`", as opposed to `XmlSchemaSet.Add(string, string)` which only specifies `null`. Or perhaps the two methods are actually slightly different.